# Convert cell to standard matrix

Tags: matlab, octave

How could I convert a cell array to a standard matrix?

For example:
`A{1}` contains a 11 lines * 2 columns matrix
`A{2}` a x lines * 2 columns (it's always two columns matrices)
...
`A{n}` a x lines * 2 columns matrix.

The number of rows, `x`, varies each time the index of the cell, `n`, changes.
In other words, each cell content is always 2 columns wide, but contains a varying quantities of rows.

I'd like to store them in a standard array B(x,1:2,n) with 2 columns and `x` varying according to the variation of `n`.

For example, if `A{1}` is 11x2, these values are stored in B like this: `B(1:11,1:2,1)`.
If `A{n}` is x*2, B would store theses values as `B(1:x,1:2,n)`.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some examples, please, of your matrices?

Comment: This will dynamically change your first dimension of the three-dimensional matrix `B`. And fill the so-far not-defined values to zeroes. Not sure if you exactly want that.

Comment: A standard (non-cell) array `B(x,1:2,n)` cannot have different `x` for each `n`

Answer (score 1):

**Generate test data:**

```
A{1} = ones( 11, 2 )
A{2} = 2 * ones( 22, 2 )
A{3} = 3 * ones( 33, 2 )

A = 

    [11x2 double]    [22x2 double]    [33x2 double]

>> whos A
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  A         1x3              1392  cell
```

**The manual approach (when you know the sizes):**

```
B( 1:11, 1:2, 1 ) = A{1}
B( 1:22, 1:2, 2 ) = A{2}
B( 1:33, 1:2, 3 ) = A{3}
```

**The looped approach:**

```
for k = 1:numel( A )
    B( 1:size( A{k},1 ), 1:2, k ) = A{k};
end
>> whos B
  Name       Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

  B         33x2x3             1584  double
```

As you can see, the largest first dimension of your matrices will define the size of the first dimension of your three-dimensional matrix, that is:

```
>> B(:, :, 2)
=
 2     2
 2     2
 2     2
 2     2
 2     2
 2     2
 ...
 2     2
 2     2
 0     0
 ...
 0     0
```

Edit: you can then also pre-allocate B:

```
B = zeros( max( cellfun('size', A, 1) ), max( cellfun('size', A, 2) ), numel( A ) )
```